# Reference for local linearization theorem

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry

I would need to reference the following seemingly very well known fact:

> If f:$M\to M$ is a diffeomorphism of finite order, then at any point in the fixed-point set of f the manifold M has coordinates with respect to which f is linear.

I've seen it called "local linearization theorem" in some lecture notes, but without reference to a textbook.

Can somebody suggest a standard reference for that?

Comment: For a much more general result (action of a compact Lie group), you can look at Bourbaki's *Lie groups and Lie algebras*, ch. 9, §9, Proposition 5.

Comment: Indeed if $G$ compact group acts continuously by smooth diffeomorphism on a manifold, fixing a point $p$, by averaging, it preserves a Riemannian metric, and then it can be shown that the action is locally conjugate to the tangent action.

Comment: abx and YCor are referring to a theorem of Bochner, which he proved exactly as YCor says.

Comment: Interesting. Is there a simple reason why one does not get into problems with resonances, as in Sternberg's Linearization Theorem?

Comment: @Abdelmalek Abdesselam: I think the simple reason is

Comment: @abx: seems your comment got cut.

Comment: @Abdelmalek Abdesselam: Yes, sorry about that. I just wanted to say that the situation is much simpler that in the Sternberg's theorem: as YCor said, yo can find an invariant metric, then $\exp$ is equivariant and you are reduced to the (easy) linear case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

S. Bochner, *Compact groups of differentiable transformations*, **Ann. of Math.** (2) 46 (1945), 372–381. MR MR0013161 (7,114g)

Comment: Thank you all for your help!